# Ansible error when trying to ping Windows 10 host. No winrm module

Tags: ansible, centos8, winrm

I'm using this command to ping a Windows host from my CentOS 8 Ansible server

```
ansible windows -m win_ping
```

But I get this output when executing it

> windows | FAILED! => {
>         "msg": "winrm or requests is not installed: No module named winrm"
> }

This is the entry for the Windows machine on my Ansible hosts file

> [w10]
> windows ansible_host=10.0.10.15
> [w10:vars]
> ansible_user=someuser
> ansible_password=somepassword
> ansible_connection=winrm
> ansible_port=5986

Winrm is enabled on the Windows machine. I also installed the `pywinrm` module with the following command, but it didn't solve my problem

```
pip3 install pywinrm
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: head -n1 $(which ansible)  # Which python is Ansible using?

Comment: @JohnMahowald #!/bin/python3

Answer (score 2):

Module or plugin requirements must be installed to the python that uses them. As this is for a plugin, it must be to the python running the `ansible` or `ansible-playbook` script.

List the installed version of pywinrm with this:

```
ansible -m python_requirements_info -a dependencies=winrm localhost
```

If the Python module could be found, it will be returned under a `valid`  key.

Also confirm that the `python` returned is the same as what you run ansible with,  `head -n1 $(which ansible)`

Comment: This was helpful.
On RedHat 7.9, ansible version 2.9.15, python 2.7.5, this works as described above.
However on MacOS/homebrew, ansible version 2.11.5, python 3.9.7, I had to change winrm to pywinrm to get a valid key.